# Dynamically changing react-modal content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

I have problem with react-modal. I have list of `SingleElement` and after click it should appear modal window with more details of clicked element. JSON with data is stored as state and from the inside of Modal I can't find way to get desired element.

Here's the modal inside `render()` function:

```
        <Modal
            isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
            onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
            onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
            chosenBeer={this.state.chosenBeer}
        >
            <h2> == Dynamically changing title of element == </h2>
            <button onClick={this.closeModal}>X</button>
            <img src="{ == Dynamically changing image == }" />
        </Modal>

        <div id="splashElements">
        {
            this.state.elements &&
            this.state.elements.map((item, index) => {
                return(<SingleElement key={index} name={item.name} href={item.href} image={item.image_url} tagline={item.tagline} onDelete={id => this.onDelete(index)} openModal={elementId => this.openModal(index)}/>)
            })
        }
        </div>
```

And here are methods responsible for showing/hiding modal window:

```
openModal = (beerId) => {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true, chosenBeer: this.state.beers[beerId]});
}

afterOpenModal = () =>{
    // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
}

closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two says. When a menu item is clicked created a function that stores the menu item to the state, then the modal can call directly from the state.

What I would do, is have a function attached to the listItem that captures the selected item and sends it through to a custom reusable modal component...

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}

handleClick(item) {
 //You would need to create a reusable modal component and import it.
return (
<ReusableModalComponent item={item}
)

}
```

Then in your ReusableModalComponent you can access everything from the list via this.props.item.src...etc

Update for your example to make your code work as is...

```
this.state.elements.map((item, index) => {
            return(<SingleElement key={index} name={item.name} href={item.href} image={item.image_url} tagline={item.tagline} onDelete={id => this.onDelete(index)} openModal={elementId => this.openModal(index)} onClick={() => this.setState({itemToShow: item, modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen}) />)
        })
```

Then, reference this.state.itemToShow.etc inside your modal

Comment: But due to what I've said and tagged I'm already using react-modal (component straightly from ReactJS GitHub)

Comment: You can literally copy and paste your Modal into a seperate ReusableModalComponent. Then you keep your code clean and use react how it was designed, this way you would also keep state clean and not overlapping into higher componetns. however, I added an updated piece of code that will work for what you want to do, without reusablemodalcomponent

Answer (score 0):

So what I understand is u rendered each item in the state.elements and each                `<SingleElement/>` component has a button and upon clicking on this button u wanna open the  modal will display the value of single element

looks like each button is gonna use openModal method. with this method we have to do 2 things. first change the `this.state.modalIsOpen` value and pass the dynamic value on to the modal body. for this, first I ll show u a javascript magic. In javascript

```
    !!undefined=false
    !!anystring=true  // pretty clear I believe
```

So first step, `this.state.modalIsOpen:undefined` should be set like so. magic will start in third step.

second step you have to pass this value to the singleModal component. in your parent component u also render a component that includes Modal so i will name it `**singleModal**.`

```
        <singleModal
          modalIsOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen} //i just show the related prop here. 
        />
```

third step in the Modal component i believe it is stateless function component.
               initially in the state modalIsOpen value was `undefined.` so with javascript magic `!!props.modalIsOpen` value is set to false. so no modal shows up.

fourth step, openModal method  activates the modal.

```
    openModal = (beerId) => {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen:this.state.elements[beerId] ,    chosenBeer:this.state.beers[beerId]});
      }
```

here is the thing Since I dont know layout about your app, I assumed that beerId is same as the **key** id value inside each `<SIngleElement key={} />`. so i pulled the single element inside the `this.state.elements`.

here is the second part of the magic. i set the modalIsOpen to `this.state.elements[beerId]`. remember that this value is what we set for the isOpen prop inside the Modal component.

```
           <Modal
            isOpen={!!props.modalIsOpen}
          />
```

this time `props.modalIsOpen=this.state.elements[beerId]` which is a string. so `!!props.modalIsOpen` will be **true** and your modal will open.

Last step, now inside the modal

```
    {props.modalIsOpen && <p>{props.modalIsOpen}</p>}
```